# SSIS - Integer column containing some Nulls, wont export

Tags: ssis

I have had another session with SSIS driving me crazy and cannot find anythign that will help me!

I have a simple SSIS Package that takes data from a flat file - one column I need to import has single digit integers 1 through 5 and the occasional NULL... which is fine.

I wish to import this column through my OLE DB Destination which points to an Integer column in my database which allows NULLs, however when I try to run the package through it keeps failing on the NULLS.

Can someone please tell me if there is a simple way for me to be able to insert thes Integer values along with the nulls in the column?

This has been driving me crazy today as there just doesn't seem to be a straight answer out there?! Or, im not looking in the right places!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW - I have 'Keep Nulls' checked on the Destination Editor... That doesnt seem to do much at all for my plight!

Comment: The exact error message "might" be helpful. Do you have unique constraints?

Comment: Furthermore - I have created a new column in my database table as a String datatype... When I point the integer column with nulls to this DB column - it imports fine and is happy enough to leave carry over the NULLs accordingly. This is blowing my mind.. its like SSIS will not allow nulls to exist in a Integer column?? I have been using the Data Type four-byte signed integer [DT_I4]

Comment: Is your file delimited or fixed width? I seem to recall if the data looks like `abc||def` it will work fine but `abc| |def`  is going to fail because the space doesn't translate to a null. Quick resolution is to import the field as DT_STR, length of 1. Have a Derived Column perform the translation from string to integer accounting for the logic for empty/nulls

Comment: The data is comma delimited and I am certain that the NULLS are being identified as such due to my String test above... (i.e. when I point the same path to a string column in the DB table, the Nulls are passed through accordingly. It is only when we try passing the data into an integer DB Table we get the problem... to give the full picture - the flat file is passing these empty values as a space (" ") so I am using a derived column to trim these - this changes them to Nulls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply though billink c!!

Comment: Can you tell us the error message you are getting?   "Failing on the NULLS" is too vague.

Comment: The first error reads: [OLE DB Destination 6 [5221]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".

Comment: Then: [OLE DB Destination 6 [5221]] Error: There was an error with input column "ATTAINED" (7593) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (5234). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate ETL faux pas!

There was actually one value that was just an empty string field... Pesky empty string field. I used a derived column function:

```
LEN(TRIM(Column Name)) == 0 ? NULL(DT_WSTR,10) : Column Name
```

to convert the empty string field to a null... Now the data imports nocely into an INT column on my database.

Sorry all... I am sure I checked this first!